# Black screen at MacOS login

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina

After starting my MacBook Pro 16” (2018) the screen stays black. Also the command strip is dark and without screen brightness controls. I can’t login. Keyboard has backlight on. What could be a fix for the problem?

I’m running Catalina 10.15.7.

I have tried SCM reset already. I can boot to recovery mode. There the screen works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Reseting the NVRAM seems to have fixed the problem.